# Compare list of parameters with each other and sort them from most to least selected

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I want to sort the list of parameters (p1, p2, p3, p4, ..., pn) according to the importance.
All parameters have to be compared with each other at best once, but not less than once.

Person will be asked to select the winner of the comparison, so every compare there is only 1 winner.

The workflow should be similar to this:

1. Compare p1:p2, p1:p3, p1:p4, p2:p3, p2:p4, p3:p4, ... as seen in the table below. Compare that many times that we can make an order without a doubt.
2. Sort the parameters from most to least winning.

```
|    | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 |
| p1 | xx | xx | xx | xx |
| p2 | p1 | xx | xx | xx |
| p3 | p3 | p2 | xx | xx |
| p4 | p1 | p4 | p3 | xx |
```

Sorted example (not correct order):
p4, p2, p3, p1

The problem with the comparison above is that there is not enough data to sort them all, so we need to compare further.

I don't know how to write an algorithm that will be suitable for human comparison of a list with around 10 parameters.

Comment: You state items are comparable, but that may not give a simple order to items. When compared, P1 may be greater then P2 and P2 may be less then P3; however; when compared, what do you do if P1 compares less than P3. Another example is non-transitive dice: http://paddy3118.blogspot.com/2016/09/non-transitive-dice-in-python.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using **Insertion sort algorithm**. I think this is quite effective way to sort small list of parameters. I will post code sometime in the future.